# (Devise) Password being required on update, even when it was left blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My user model fails to save because password and password_confirmation can't be blank. This happens when:

- Updating the user on edit_user_registration and leaving the password and password confirmation blank. This is where I first noticed
- On the console, immediately after loading an object and calling save.

Devise will validate the presence of password if password_required?

```
  validates_presence_of     :password, :if => :password_required?

  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

This is my rails console output:

```
  Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
  1.9.3p374 :001 > u = User.last
    User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   => #<User id: 9, name: "Name", email: "name@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$oCL2K0nEa8LxaMGuC1oyNOuwIHk8l/IOW.AylGcWTYj3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2013-02-06 20:56:14", last_sign_in_at: "2013-02-06 20:52:01", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2013-02-07 22:04:01", confirmation_sent_at: "2013-02-07 22:03:25", unconfirmed_email: nil, authentication_token: nil, created_at: "2013-02-06 20:52:00", updated_at: "2013-02-07 22:04:31"> 
  1.9.3p374 :002 > u.save
     (0.2ms)  BEGIN
     (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   => false 
  1.9.3p374 :003 > u.errors
   => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f832c04f090 @base=#<User id: 9, name: "Name", email: "name@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$oCL2K0nEa8LxaMGuC1oyNOuwIHk8l/IOW.AylGcWTYj3...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2013-02-06 20:56:14", last_sign_in_at: "2013-02-06 20:52:01", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2013-02-07 22:04:01", confirmation_sent_at: "2013-02-07 22:03:25", unconfirmed_email: nil, authentication_token: nil, created_at: "2013-02-06 20:52:00", updated_at: "2013-02-07 22:04:31">, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank"], :password_confirmation=>["can't be blank"]}> 
  1.9.3p374 :004 > !u.persisted? || !u.password.nil? || !u.password_confirmation.nil?
   => false
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your whole User model? There must be something else going on here. It's odd that you're getting the :password_confirmation=>["can't be blank"] error. You have a validation for that somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It had to be somewhere else, a good night of sleep later and your recommendation make it obvious. I answer my own question explaining the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @rainkinz, I went back to the basics (the user model) and took a closer look. I found out that a module I was importing was adding an extra

```
validates :email, :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

I was able to see this by running in the console :

```
User.validators

 ...
 #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fb80fbcd260
   @attributes=[:email, :password, :password_confirmation],
   @options={}>,
 ...
```

This is different than the validations devise puts in, which contain:

```
@options={:if=>:password_required?}>,
```

Removing those solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in your update method.

```
user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    unless user.blank?
      if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:notice] = "User updated successfully."
        redirect_to "somwhere"
      else
        render :action => 'edit'
      end
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
```

if you  don't want to update the old password then add these line before updation so the new code will be:

```
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        unless user.blank?
          params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
          params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            flash[:notice] = "User updated successfully."
            redirect_to "somwhere"
          else
            render :action => 'edit'
          end
        else
          render :action => 'edit'
        end
```

write somthing like this in user.rb model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :locakable
```

Comment: There is no need to do this, because the registration is being handled by Devise. On the registrations controller 'resource.update_with_password(resource_params)' is called (this is current password, not password and password_confirmation), where `params[:password].blank?` both password and password_confirmation get deleted from the params before attemping a normal 'update_attributes(params, *options)' And this is something happening on the model, because I was able to replicate the problem using the console alone.

Comment: Also, instead of find_by_id, which will be deprecated soon (See Rails 4), use find(params[:id]) instead or , the more generic, where(...).first. And yes, my user model looks very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, but the solution that worked for me was calling devise's method again with `super` after doing what I wanted. For example:

```
def password_required?
  return false if some_check?
  super
end
```

Credits for this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32186236/4812034) that shed light on me.