# How to insert an already encrypted password on devise model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, encryption, devise

I am a newbie in rails. I would like to ask if it's possible to insert an encrypted password(encrypted using devise default encryption) to devise model?

e.g:

> ```
>   User.csv
>
>       id,name,encrypted_password
>       1,dude,$2a$10$0.xEu5LvDbnmGVIqgIab8ej5o2b3eKa8KLevsg5bxIX0SHSOl5gye
> ```

I want to read this csv file and then insert the data to User model.
But I realized that you can't insert the already encrypted password normally on `encrypted_password` of User model. I'm thinking to decrypt the password but they say that it is bad for the system's security.

Update: It can now insert an encrypted password but the inserted password is different to the one on the csv since the devise automatically encrypts the password before inserting it to the database. Is there a way for devise model to detect if the password is already encrypted before inserting it to the database?

Comment: You can't decrypt the password. I believe that the only way is to manually insert those records in the database, so you'd skip Rails and devise. So, modify that CSV so you can just import it to your database (so "import CSV to mySQL/pqSQL").

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm trying to create a csv import function on which an admin can upload a csv. The system will then read the csv and insert the data to the database.

Comment: It seems like I can insert a plain text password to devise model but not the encrypted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can set the encrypted_password value directly:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.update_attribute(:encrypted_password, "$2a$10$0.xEu5LvDbnmGVIqgIab8ej5o2b3eKa8KLevsg5bxIX0SHSOl5gye")
```

But you should make sure that you're not setting 'password', if you do this won't work as it'll encrypt it again, so

```
u = User.new
u.password = 'foo'
u.password_confirmation = 'foo'
u.encrypted_password = "$2a$10$0.xEu5LvDbnmGVIqgIab8ej5o2b3eKa8KLevsg5bxIX0SHSOl5gye" # this line will be ignored
u.save


u = User.new
u.encrypted_password = "$2a$10$0.xEu5LvDbnmGVIqgIab8ej5o2b3eKa8KLevsg5bxIX0SHSOl5gye" # this line will now work
u.save
```

Comment: Just tried it. it failed on validation, asking for password to be provided. I think this would work if I somehow turn the validation off. I'll see if I can turn it off when uploading a csv. Thank you

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much. For those wondering how i turn off the validation. Credits to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185562/devise-create-users-without-password